# ErrorDocument in .htaccess, is it possible to use relative path?

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, path, errordocument

This doesn't work:

```
ErrorDocument 401 ../../src/wrong_pwd.php
```

it renders the path as text, it really prints

```
../../src/wrong_pwd.php
```

and doesn't output the real file.

If I put the absolute path it will render the contents of `/var/www/home`  (I don't really know why, maybe it's something in httpd.conf?)

How can I do that?

Comment: This is a big limitation of ErrorDocument inside an .htacess, and there is no good substitute for handling HTTP errors in a subsite. Is it possible to use an expression for the current working directory? Example: "ErrorDocument, %{CURDIR}/error.php". Answer to my own question: no, there is no way to write a universal .htaccess that can be used for multiple subdirectories of a website. There is no way to specify an error handler in the current directory.

Answer (score 2):

The [docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#errordocument) say:

> URLs can begin with a slash (/) for
>   local web-paths (relative to the
>   DocumentRoot), or be a full URL which
>   the client can resolve. Alternatively,
>   a message can be provided to be
>   displayed by the browser.

`../../src/wrong_pwd.php` doesn't begin with a slash so I expect Apache treats it as a message. It looks like you can't return a document which is outside the `DocumentRoot` so I suspect what you want will never work (this is sensible; after all, the client has to be able to retrieve the document in case of an error).

You might be able to use `Alias` to alias the error page to a location outside the document root. Something like:

```
Alias /error/wrong_pwd.php /path/to/src/wrong_pwd.php
ErrorDocument 401 /error/wrong_pwd.php
```

Untested, YMMV, etc. You might need to explicitly grant access to this directory with a <`Directory`> block; see the [mod_alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#alias) documentation. Of course, there are security concerns here -- generally you don't want to expose your source to the world. (If this is the case perhaps you could make a lightweight, web-visible PHP wrapper which `include()s` the `/path/to/src/wrong_pwd.php`...)

Comment: Yes I'm going to use a wrapper, the problem is I can't catch this error properly. Using alias gives an error on error.log:  
`Alias not allowed here`...

Comment: Server error! Error message:  ....htaccess Alias not allowed here

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a symlink?

```
ln -s ../../src/wrong_pwd.php src/wrong_pwd.php
```